# Display firebase images in icarousel

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, icarousel

I am using icarousel to display images from my firebase database. I have five UIImages

```
var ImageOne = UIImage()
var ImageTwo = UIImage()
var ImageThree = UIImage()
var ImageFour = UIImage()
var ImageFive = UIImage()
```

And I use this code to get all five images from firebase storage into my UIImages

```
 if let stringImage5 = self.imagesFive {
                    AppDelegate.instance().showActivityIndicator()
                    let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage5)")

                    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicator()
                            self.ImageFive = UIImage(data: data!)!


                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }



                    })}
```

Now, I want to display the images in icarousel and in order to do that I have to put them into an array so I did this:

```
imageArray = [self.ImageOne, self.ImageTwo, self.ImageThree, self.ImageFour, self.ImageFive]
```

Now this function is supposed to display all five images:

```
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var imageView: UIImageView!

        imageView.image = UIImage(imageArray = [self.ImageOne, self.ImageTwo, self.ImageThree, self.ImageFour, self.ImageFive])
        return imageView

    }
```

But no images are displaying.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of async stuff going on, and I assume that you're probably creating (and displaying) the carousel before the images have been downloaded, and not refreshing the carousel with the new images.

I'd take a look at Zero to App ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE), [source](https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd)), as it explains how to asynchronously populate a list with images, which is basically what you're doing.

Also, no idea how iCarousel works, but I assume that your `viewForItemAt index` wants an image, not an image of an array...

```
let imageArray = [self.ImageOne, self.ImageTwo, self.ImageThree, self.ImageFour, self.ImageFive]
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var imageView: UIImageView!
        imageView.image = imageArray[index];
        return imageView
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that a variable at the very top var imageArray: [UIImage] = [] and the imageArray = [] is in my viewdidLoad, so the return imageView in the func carousel is not returning an image